# How to get second column in a row to go on top of the first column when the page shrinks using html/css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, multiple-columns

below you'll see I have a div container that holds one row with two columns of equal width and height. The image is on the left side and the text is on the right. I'm currently using @media so that when the screen reaches a certain width, both columns will go on top of each other and they'll be one column. My question is, is there any way to make the second column go above the first column when my @media activates instead of vice-versa? Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="resources-flex-container" >
    <div class="resources-img-section">
        <img src="../images/resources.png" alt="" class="resources-img">
    </div>

    <div class="resources-main-content">
        <p class="resources-section-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</p>

        <p class="resources-section-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla quibusdam rerum, saepe exercitationem earum quas architecto, autem, accusantium facere aliquam repellat minus quia quis eum ad? Cupiditate, corporis quae? Libero!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.resources-flex-container {
    padding-left: 5%; 
    padding-right: 5%; 
    background-color: rgb(238,43,42, .15);
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

@media (min-width: 56.25em){
    .resources-flex-container {
        display: flex;  
    }
}

  .resources-main-content {
    flex: 1;  
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }

  .resources-section-title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600; text-align: center;
  }

  .resources-section-description {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
  }

  .resources-button-section {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .resources-button {
    color:white;
    width: 270px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background-color: #CE4A4A;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 1.75rem;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: .7%;
    padding-bottom: .7%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    border: 0;
  }

  .resources-img-section {
    flex: .75 0 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }

  .resources-img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%; 
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add flex-direction: column-reverse;  property in @media query class according to your min-width and max-width

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.resources-flex-container {
  padding-left: 5%; 
  padding-right: 5%; 
  background-color: rgb(238,43,42, .15);
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 56.25em ){
  .resources-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;  
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .resources-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;  
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .resources-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  
  }
}

.resources-main-content {
  flex: 1;  
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.resources-section-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600; text-align: center;
}

.resources-section-description {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.resources-button-section {
  text-align: center;
}

.resources-button {
  color:white;
  width: 270px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background-color: #CE4A4A;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: .7%;
  padding-bottom: .7%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  border: 0;
}

.resources-img-section {
  flex: .75 0 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.resources-img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 70%; 
  height: 80%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow:  0px 0px 5px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="resources-flex-container" >
    <div class="resources-img-section">
        <img src="../images/resources.png" alt="" class="resources-img">
    </div>

    <div class="resources-main-content">
        <p class="resources-section-title">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit</p>

        <p class="resources-section-description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla quibusdam rerum, saepe exercitationem earum quas architecto, autem, accusantium facere aliquam repellat minus quia quis eum ad? Cupiditate, corporis quae? Libero!
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to align image in top. you can add align-items: flex-start; in resources-flex-container class